# Separate getter and setter declarations

Tags: c#, interface, getter-setter

How can I separately declare a getter and a setter for a property?

For exemple, say I want to create the following hierarchy:

```
interface IReadOnlyFoo
{
    string Value { get; }
}

interface IFoo : IReadOnlyFoo
{
    string Value { set; }
}

class BasicFoo : IFoo
{
    string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The compiler is compaining because `IFoo.Value` is hiding `IReadOnlyFoo.Value`, which is not what I want to do. I want to "merge" the getter and setter declarations.

I've had a look at how the .NET Framwork declares the `IReadOnlyList` and `IList` interfaces, but it's done in a different way.

How could I acheive what I want to do ? Can I do that with a property or do I really have to create separate `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` methods instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change your interface definition to

```
interface IReadOnlyFoo
{
    string Value { get;  }
}

interface IReadWriteFoo
{
    string Value { get; set; }
}

class BasicFoo : IFoo, IReadOnlyFoo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's close to what I would have liked to have, but there's a small problem in this case : all the read only properties and methods that would exist in the IReadOnlyFoo interface, such as Contains(), Count or whatever, all have to be duplicated in the IReadWriteFoo interface, which can cause a good amount of redundancy. In this case I might rather favor the use of Get and Set methods over a property. It might been cleaner despite being less elegant.

Comment: You could overcome this problem by introducing a third interface, that contains all the shared definitions and use this Interface as base for IReadOnlyFoo and iReadWriteFoo.

Comment: Yes indeed. I will try this. Thank you. Feel free to edit your answer with that suggestion.

Comment: The simpler solution would be to have `IReadWriteFoo` inherit from `IReadOnlyFoo`.

Comment: After some thinking, I'll just stick with using separate Get and Set methods, because it feels more natural than having a "write only" interface, which has no real reason to exist on its own, just for the purpose of gettng around a limitation of C# properties.

Answer (score 2):

When you implement the interface the two members would be merged since you don't have a get method in IFoo.Value.

```cs
    interface IReadOnlyFoo
    {
        string Value { get; }
    }

    interface IFoo : IReadOnlyFoo
    {
        new string Value { set; }
    }

    class BasicFoo : IFoo
    {
       public string Value { get;  set; }
    }
```

As long as you are using implicit implementations for the interfaces it would behave as you intended. on the other hand, if you wish to have two different behaviors for the members of the interface then you want to use explicit implementations. You can find an example here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/how-to-explicitly-implement-members-of-two-interfaces

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I would have to add the "new" keyword, just like you did, for the compiler not to tell me that `IFoo.Value` hides `IReadOnlyFoo.Value`. I'm not really sure about what it would involve to do so. Would it create two separate properties that need to be disambiguated ? I don't know but I can feel problems coming later on with that.

Comment: These are interfaces they define a group of related functionalities. Hence as long as you are using implicit implementations for the interfaces it would behave as you intended. on the other hand, if you wish to have two different behaviors for the members of the interface then you want to use explicit implementations.

You can find an example here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/how-to-explicitly-implement-members-of-two-interfaces

Comment: If I did understand the  question correctly, the IFoo.Value sould offer a getter and a setter. So you should consider adding the Get; to the defintion.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to change in your code is to add a getter to the `Value` property in the `IFoo` interface.

Semantically speaking, `IFoo` is a specific kind of `IReadOnlyFoo` that adds another capability to it's base type (the Setter of the `Value` property).
This is the exact definition of inheritance in object oriented programming - a child type is a more specific version of it's base type and is adding capabilities to it.

```
interface IReadOnlyFoo
{
    string Value { get;  }
}

interface IFoo : IReadOnlyFoo
{
    new string Value { get; set; }
}

class BasicFoo : IFoo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This code is perfectly valid and will give you exactly what you're looking for.

This way, if you have a reference of type `IReadOnlyFoo` to an instance of `BasicFoo`, the `Value` property is indeed readonly, but if your reference type is `IFoo` it's a read / write property.

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/DZGEU63402)

Comment: This implementation gives you the warning: 'Rextester.IFoo.Value' hides inherited member 'Rextester.IReadOnlyFoo.Value'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Rextester doesn't show warnings by default so I've missed it. Anyway it's not a problem because the hiding is intended so it's just a matter of adding the `new` keyword.